# Converting an integer $k$ into a pair of integers $(i,j)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let us consider
\begin{array}{ccc}
  k & i & j \\
  1 & 2 & 1 \\
  2 & 3 & 1 \\
  3 & 4 & 1 \\
  4 & 3 & 2 \\
  5 & 4 & 2 \\
  6 & 4 & 3 
\end{array}
and
\begin{array}{ccc}
  k & i & j \\
  1 & 2 & 1 \\
  2 & 3 & 1 \\
  3 & 4 & 1 \\
  4 & 5 & 1 \\
  5 & 3 & 2 \\
  6 & 4 & 2 \\
  7 & 5 & 2 \\
  8 & 4 & 3 \\
  9 & 5 & 3 \\
  10 &5  &4  
\end{array}
I'm searching for a mathematical formula that, for these two examples and from the value $k$, gives the corresponding couple of indices $(i,j)$. This formula seems to be very hard to find. For instance, in the first example, if $k=3$ the corresponding couple is $(4,1)$, if $k=6$ we have $(i,j)=(4,3)$; in the second example, if $k=2$ the couple is $(3,1)$ and so on.

Is it a well-known problems? Does anyone have any suggestions? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Can you please explain your charts?  I have no idea how $k$ and $(i,j)$ are related.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I've edited my post.

Comment: Where are these numbers coming from?  The $i$ column appears to go $(2,3,4,5)$ then $(3,4,5)$ then $(4,5)$ and finally $(5)$.  On the other hand, the $j$ column appears to go $(1111)$ $(222)$ $(33)$ $(4)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the $j$-column, we can see that it partitions the $k$'s into groups of sequentially decreasing sizes.

Let's consider a sequence $\{P_i^{(n)} = (n-i+1) : i = 1, \ldots n\}$, it's partial sum is $S_r^{(n)} = \sum_{i=1}^r P_i^{(n)} = r(2n+1-r)/2, \, r = 0,\ldots,n$.

Define $$J(k;n) = j\quad\text{such that}\quad S_{j-1}^{(n)} \lt k \le S_j^{(n)}.$$
and $$I(k;n) = k-S_{J(k;n)-1}^{(n)}+J(k;n).$$

For $n = 3$, $\{S_r^{(3)} : r = 0, 1, 2, 3\} = \{0, 3, 5, 6\},$ and $\{J(k;3) : k = 1,\ldots,6\} = \{1,1,1,2,2,3\}$, and $\{I(k;3) : k = 1,\ldots,6\} = \{2,3,4,3,4,4\}.$ This matches the first set in the question.

We can also see that the $n = 4$ matches the second set.

Comment: Thank you! It is very interesting. Might you explain the proof of $I(k;n)$ formula?

Comment: @Mark  Since there is only a limited number of cases, so it's not a general 'proof', rather, it's a case by case verification. It can be done easily by looking at the difference between the $k$-column and $i$-column.